# How can I use the CHATGPT chat completion API in Java to retrieve previous context in a new question and obtain the corresponding result?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have to use CHATGPT chat completion API in Java to retrieve previous context in a new question (Please review all the previous context and provide a summary of it.) and obtain the corresponding result. for that i am using:

API:

```
curl https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $OPENAI_API_KEY" \
  -d '{
    "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    "messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "Hello!"}]
  }'
```

- used chat completion api
- used edit api

Response:

```
{
    "id": "chatcmpl-76eCdoZ4qHySmqBTsX0e97NqTOLgs",
    "object": "chat.completion",
    "created": 1681818863,
    "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo-0301",
    "usage": {
        "prompt_tokens": 16,
        "completion_tokens": 29,
        "total_tokens": 45
    },
    "choices": [
        {
            "message": {
                "role": "assistant",
                "content": "**As an AI language model, I cannot check the clauses without specific context. Please provide more information or context so that I can assist you accurately.**"
            },
            "finish_reason": "stop",
            "index": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The API request needs to be called Recursively by adding the message object received in response. As per [documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/chat/introduction) , Every response will include a finish_reason(stop,length,content_filter,null). In the below code, if the reason is 'length',It will append the last message object received in the response(chatResp) and this will be called recursively till the finish reason is 'stop'.

```
ChatRequest request = new ChatRequest(model,temperature);


do{
    HttpResponse<String> response  =  callAi(request);
    if(response!=null ) {
        if(response.getStatus()==200) {
        try {
            chatResp = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response.getBody().toString(), ChatResponse.class);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
        if(chatResp!=null) {
        // Use the response as required
        }
        // if 'length' is the finish reason
        if(chatResp.getChoices().get(0).getFinish_reason().equals("length")) {
            request.messages.add(chatResp.getChoices().get(0).getMessage());
        }
    }
    }           
}while(chatResp!=null && !chatResp.getChoices().get(0).getFinish_reason().equals("stop"));
```

Comment: I tried, but it's not working. I want it to take all the previous context and finally ask one question, to which ChatGPT API will respond.It's possible on chatgpt plus.

Comment: To your original message array, add the message object ({"role": "assistant","content": "**As an AI language model, I cannot check the clauses ......**"},) received in response as it is and a new message object to the same array with your next question as {"role": "user", "content": "How are you today ?"}. Thus your new request has message array with three objects. Since API doesn't maintain any session, you will have to tell API the prior context and keep communicating to it.

Comment: https://github.com/ashishsukhija/chatgpt/blob/master/src/com/chatgpt/completion/ChatGptMain.java

Comment: Thanks, I followed this link.
but now I am encountering a length issue. The context I am using is too big, so I divided it into several parts. However, when I passed it into another request, it's showing a token limit error.

{
  "error": {
    "message": "This model's maximum context length is 4097 tokens. However, your messages resulted in 5948 tokens. Please reduce the length of the messages.",
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "param": "messages",
    "code": "context_length_exceeded"
  }
}

Comment: Right, The API has this limitation. However to tackle that, you can omit the message objects from top of the array and just leave the last few message objects that can help the API to understand the context of the discussion.

Comment: ok, thanks. but its not working